# Can Arduino relay module change the speed of fan?

Tags: arduino, sensors, temperature, relay, pwm

I have a 240V fan connected to Arduino 5V relay. Is it possible to change the speed of fan from low to medium to high depends on the temperature?

I've tried to use the following code but I don't see my 240V fan changing the speed. It just turn on and off.

```cpp
int fan = 13;
int fanSpeed;
int tempMin = 25;
int tempMax = 75; 

void loop(){
if ((temp >= tempMin) && (temp <= tempMax)) {
    fanSpeed = map(temp, tempMin, tempMax, 32, 255);
    analogWrite(fan, fanSpeed);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your circuit (schematic) and the relay type. Also, this might be more appropriate for arduino stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

Using analogWrite() will not cause a electromechanical relay to switch partially on - it will either cause the relay to be damaged if the PWM frequency is low enough, or have no effect - the relay will be on above some value. Even if you could switch a relay partly on, it might not make the fan run slower - if it's a synchronous motor, its speed will be determined by the mains' frequency, not the voltage. Some fans aren't synchronous, and can be voltage controlled, as discussed on [the electronics sister site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/what-is-used-to-control-ac-motor-speed)

If your fan has multiple speed switches, then you might be able to duplicate the effect by having multiple relays, one replacing each switch. These energize different coils in the motor to changes the speed, [such as in this wiring diagram](http://www.disconnecteddocumentary.com/furnace-blower-motor-wiring-diagram/bracket-direction-furnace-blower-motor-wiring-diagram-standard-course-demonstration-actual-primary-knowledgable-logical/)

Otherwise you will need a fan with DC or BLDC motor, where you can more directly vary the speed using PWM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry to ask again, is it possible to change the brightness of a light bulb by using the same relay?

Comment: Relays are effectively just plain change-over switches. If there's a way of doing it with just a plain switch, then you can do it with a relay. You need a dimmer rather than a switch to change the brightness of a light bulb.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly impossible!! It's as impossible as making your breakfast using a program without any hardware. Relay module can only turn things on or off. They can't alter the resistance. Firstly, you haven't defined `temp`. Moreover, since you are using PWM, this code can easily and conveniently destroy your relay module.